# Importing excel data into nested dictionary

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I have a spreadsheet that I am trying to import the data into a set of nested python dictionaries.  Essentially the spreadsheet has columns for site, building, floor, room, row, and rack.  I would like the data structure to look like this:

```
sites = [
  {
    "name": "",
    "descr": "",
    "buildings": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "descr": "",
        "floors": [
          {
            "name": "",
            "descr": "",
            "rooms": [
              {
                "name": "",
                "descr": "",
                "rows": [
                  {
                    "name": "",
                    "descr": "",
                    "racks": [
                      {
                        "name": "",
                        "descr": ""
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

An example of the spreadsheet would be:

```
+------+---------------+----------+----------------+-------+-------------+------+------------+-----+-----------+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| site | site_descr    | building | building_descr | floor | floor_descr | room | room_descr | row | row_descr | rack | rack_descr | rack_dn                                                               |
+------+---------------+----------+----------------+-------+-------------+------+------------+-----+-----------+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| dc1  | Data Center 1 | alpha    | Alpha Building | 1     | Floor 1     | 100  | Room 100   | A   | Row A     | A5   | Rack A5    | uni/fabric/site-dc1/building-alpha/floor-1/room-100/row-A/rack-A5 |
+------+---------------+----------+----------------+-------+-------------+------+------------+-----+-----------+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| dc1  | Data Center 1 | alpha    | Alpha Building | 1     | Floor 1     | 100  | Room 100   | A   | Row A     | A5   | Rack A5    | uni/fabric/site-dc1/building-alpha/floor-1/room-100/row-A/rack-A5 |
+------+---------------+----------+----------------+-------+-------------+------+------------+-----+-----------+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| dc1  | Data Center 1 | alpha    | Alpha Building | 1     | Floor 1     | 200  | Room 200   | A   | Row A     | A5   | Rack A5    | uni/fabric/site-dc1/building-alpha/floor-1/room-200/row-A/rack-A5 |
+------+---------------+----------+----------------+-------+-------------+------+------------+-----+-----------+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| dc1  | Data Center 1 | alpha    | Alpha Building | 1     | Floor 1     | 100  | Room 100   | B   | Row B     | B5   | Rack B5    | uni/fabric/site-dc1/building-alpha/floor-1/room-100/row-B/rack-B5 |
+------+---------------+----------+----------------+-------+-------------+------+------------+-----+-----------+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| dc1  | Data Center 1 | alpha    | Alpha Building | 2     | Floor 2     | 100  | Room 100   | A   | Row A     | A7   | Rack A7    | uni/fabric/site-dc1/building-alpha/floor-2/room-100/row-A/rack-A7 |
+------+---------------+----------+----------------+-------+-------------+------+------------+-----+-----------+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| dc2  | Data Center 2 | beta     | Beta Building  | 5     | Floor 5     | 200  | Room 200   | B   | Row B     | B5   | Rack B5    | uni/fabric/site-dc2/building-beta/floor-5/room-200/row-B/rack-B5  |
+------+---------------+----------+----------------+-------+-------------+------+------------+-----+-----------+------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What is the best way to get this into my data structure?  The pyexcel module can import records which essentially creates a list of dictionaries with each row as an entry in the list.  I'm having problems with the logic to restructure this...

Should I initialize the structure before the for loops?  Should I just build the structure as I populate it?  If I initialize the structure with blanks like below, I would need to make sure my first row fills in those blanks which makes me think the latter might be the better option.

Comment: This question would greatly benefit from a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.  Specifically there is no sample data, nor any code you have already tried.

Comment: @StephenRauch I updated my post with the spreadsheet i am working with.  I don't have any real code yet because I'm having trouble even getting started.  I feel like i need to use the "setdefault" dictionary option to do some of this.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the thing to do is to iterate over the column names, look for a dictionary with the right name for the column, create it if it doesn't exist and then advance into its array of children:

```
import pprint

columns = ['site', 'building', 'floor', 'room', 'row', 'rack']
keys = ['buildings', 'floors', 'rooms', 'rows', 'racks']

def find(seq, pred):
    try:
        found = next(x for x in seq if pred(x))
    except StopIteration:
        found = None
    return found

def add_record(sites, record):
    array = sites
    for index, column in enumerate(columns):
        name = record[column]
        descr = record[column + '_descr']
        dictionary = find(array, lambda x: x['name'] == name)
        if dictionary is None:
            dictionary = {'name': name, 'descr' : descr}
            if column != 'rack':
                dictionary[keys[index]] = []
            array.append(dictionary)
        if column != 'rack':
            array = dictionary[keys[index]]
        else:
            dictionary['rack_dn'] = record['rack_dn']



def main():
    records = [{'site': 'dc1', 'site_descr' : 'Data Center 1', 'building' : 'alpha',
                'building_descr': 'Alpha Building', 'floor' : 1, 'floor_descr' : 'Floor 1',
                'room' : 100, 'room_descr' : 'Room 100', 'row' : 'A', 'row_descr': 'Row A',
                'rack': 'A5', 'rack_descr' : 'Rack A5',
                'rack_dn' : 'uni/fabric/site-dc1/building-alpha/floor-1/room-100/row-A/rack-A5'},
                {'site': 'dc1', 'site_descr' : 'Data Center 1', 'building' : 'alpha',
                'building_descr': 'Alpha Building', 'floor' : 1, 'floor_descr' : 'Floor 1',
                'room' : 200, 'room_descr' : 'Room 200', 'row' : 'A', 'row_descr': 'Row A',
                'rack': 'A5', 'rack_descr' : 'Rack A5',
                'rack_dn' : 'uni/fabric/site-dc1/building-alpha/floor-1/room-200/row-A/rack-A5'},
                {'site': 'dc2', 'site_descr' : 'Data Center 2', 'building' : 'beta',
                'building_descr': 'Beta Building', 'floor' : 5, 'floor_descr' : 'Floor 5',
                'room' : 200, 'room_descr' : 'Room 200', 'row' : 'B', 'row_descr': 'Row B',
                'rack': 'B5', 'rack_descr' : 'Rack B5',
                'rack_dn' : 'uni/fabric/site-dc2/building-beta/floor-5/room-200/row-B/rack-B5'}]
    sites = []
    for record in records:
        add_record(sites, record)
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
    pp.pprint(sites)
```

Comment: I think this is pretty close.  When I run it, it looks to create the structure that I need however all my 'descr' keys are empty when I look at the output.  I tried reworking the columns object to add site_descr, building_descr, etc since those are columns but that errors out with an 'IndexError: list index out of range' error.

Comment: @mikey, I've updated my answer to retrieve the `*_descr` columns and the `rack_dn`

Comment: That appears to work well.  Thank you so much!  I removed the rack_dn part because I've been meaning to remove that from the spreadsheet.  Now I just need to see if I can figure out what the code is actually doing...

Comment: You're welcome. It works as I described so hopefully is fathomable.